# How to rewrite $X^{\prime} X b=X^{\prime} y$

Tags: linear-algebra

To prove the result of Frisch-Waugh, we write out the normal equations $X^{\prime} X b=X^{\prime} y$ in terms of the partitioned matrix $X=\left(\begin{array}{ll}X_1 & X_2\end{array}\right)$.

This results in:

$$
\begin{aligned}
& X_1^{\prime} X_1 b_1+X_1^{\prime} X_2 b_2=X_1^{\prime} y \\
& X_2^{\prime} X_1 b_1+X_2^{\prime} X_2 b_2=X_2^{\prime} y
\end{aligned}
$$

**Question**

Can please be shown the steps needed to obtain the two equations?

Comment: Where do the names "Frisch-Waugh" come from ?

Comment: @jeanMarie https://towardsdatascience.com/the-fwl-theorem-or-how-to-make-all-regressions-intuitive-59f801eb3299

Comment: If $X:=\left(\begin{array}{ll}X_1 & X_2\end{array}\right)$, we have $X^TX=\binom{X_1}{X_2}\left(\begin{array}{ll}X_1 & X_2\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{ll}X'_1X_1 & X'_1X_2\\ X'_2X_1 & X'_2X_2\end{array}\right)$ using block computations. Same operations on the RHS.